# Ubuntu does not recognize HP envy 4501

Tags: printing, hp

Ubuntu won't recognize my HP envy 4501. I have tried plugging in the usb: it won't notice it at all. I tried running setup from disk and it said archive manager is in error. I'm new to Linux. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install the driver of the printer. To do that, you have to go to Printers -> Add new printer and follow the instructions. You should look for the model  of you printer. If it does not work you can also specify an external source for the driver and at that point you can use your CD.